# Is there a way using Only CSS to display the value of an attribute as html and text on a page?

Tags: html, css

If I have this html:

```
<ul>
<li attr="Hi Bob">Boring Text</li>
</ul>
```

Can I display "Hi Bob" as an element using only CSS?

Hi Bob  o  Boring Text

As an aside, is it possible to add the value of this attribute using only CSS to a separate element before the element the attribute is in?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible with the [HTML5 `data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

```css
li::before {
  content: attr(data-attr) " o ";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-attr="Hi Bob">Boring Text</li>
</ul>
```

Simply add an attribute to your HTML tag with the prefix `data-` (e.g.: `data-test`). Now you're able to access this attribute in CSS with the `attr()` function (e.g.: `attr(data-test)`).

Comment: I was thinking of a separate element or independent white space before the element the attribute is in.  Not sure if that's possible?

Comment: @RetroCoder show us what kind of result are you looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can use the attr as content on a pseudo before element - but be aware that though the user can see the text it isn't actually in an element in the DOM so it probably won't be read out by screen readers - i.e. it's not a good way if that text is important rather than just a nice embellishment.

If you want to place it far from the actual element you could position it, but this snippet just puts it immediately before with an added space:

```css
ul li[attr]::before {
  content: attr(attr) ' ';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li attr="Hi Bob">Boring Text</li>
</ul>
```

Note: although browsers will pick up any attribute name - in this case 'attr' - the standard for non-standard attributes, i.e. ones you have created yourself, is to start them with data-.